# external plugin not load first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with this site: http://www.gm-impianti.srl/index.html

when I open the site, and from the menu, i open the "portfolio" page, the instagram plugin is not loaded. If I load the page again, the plugin works. why?

this is the js that is not loaded on the first start:

```
<script src = "https://apps.elfsight.com/p/platform.js"> </script>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you include the rest of your code?

Comment: Can you see the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your scripts from

```
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apps.elfsight.com/p/platform.js" ></script>
```

to

```
 <script src="https://apps.elfsight.com/p/platform.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```